# JavaScript file line breaks with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, string, compiler-construction

I'm working on a PHP script that compiles a JavaScript framework. Right now I'm using the following code to create line breaks in JavaScript files, but I'm guessing there is a better way to do this?

```
// Line break, can this be written better?
$line_break = '

';

// Get JavaScript files
$js_file_core = file_get_contents('js/core.js', true);
$js_file_timers = file_get_contents('js/timers.js', true);

// Add a line break between files and combine them
$compiled_js = $js_file_core . $line_break . $js_file_timers;
```

Comment: why cant you use "\n" to write line breaks?

Comment: why do you need linebreaks, anyway?

Comment: /n causes a compiler error, doesn't work.

Comment: Please use '\' not '/'  :D .. if you do it wrong, it wont work :)

Comment: Returns the following when I try /n

Parse error: Illegal token in file 'game.js' on line 12

Comment: That's why you should use `\n`.

Comment: Can't you just use a regular white space character instead of line breaks? Pretty sure it'll have the same result (as long as your code is properly semi-colon'd) unless you're coding in coffeescript or something that relies on proper indenting.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct and the first one posted, no prob. =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People above told you about using "\n" already. I will point out the quotes. Many people may try this with single quotes ('). If you try this with single quotes like '\n' you will just print out \n. Use double quotes instead: "\n"

Makes difference.

Comment: Way to think outside the box. Thanks man.

$line_break = "\n\n"; not $line_break = '\n\n';

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$line_break = "\n";
```

for a line break.
Note the double quotes and not single. the \n must be in double quotes for it to work.

Comment: Returns an error in the JavaScript as an illegal character, doesn't work.

Comment: Huh? It is a line break, Are you sure you are using double quotes and NOT single quotes and the correct \ ? Are you sure the error is from this or perhaps an error in your actual javascript

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a constant, [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), to aid in cross-platform support of linebreaks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe '\n' is better for linux users. people always use '\n' to break lines, not '\r\n' which used in dos and not '\r' in mac-os.

Answer (score 1):

// Line break, can this be written better? Yes!, use \n
In PHP "\n" forces a new line character!

```
$line_break = "\n";// prints a newline!
```

Comment: Why the concatenation? Why not just `"\n\n"`?

Comment: hahaha, just to make him understand that \n\n is not a ONE new line. A peice of code is worth a 100 letters(which i cant afford cuz am lazy :p)